# Verifying an example of sum of subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, examples-counterexamples

Book: Linear Algebra Done Right 3E

Here's an example from the textbook that I cannot make sense of:

Suppose that $U = \{(x,x,y,y) \in \mathbf{F^4}: x,y\in\mathbf{F}\}$ and $W = \{(x,x,x,y) \in \mathbf{F^4}: x,y\in \mathbf{F} \}$. Then $$U+W = \{ (x,x,y,z)\in \mathbf{F^4}: x,y,z\in \mathbf{F} \}$$

To me it makes sense that $$U+W = \{ (2x,2x,x+y,2y)\in \mathbf{F^4}: x,y\in \mathbf{F} \}$$

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @RafaelHolanda, No, [SOULed_Outt](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/135045/souled-outt) is not right. See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1913893/26369).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be a little confused about [set-builder notation](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/set-builder-notation.html). $U$ is the set of all four-tuples where the first two and last two things are the same. $W$ is the set of all four-tuples where the first three things are the same. Your answer is wrong because of examples like $(1,1,2,2)\in U$, $(4,4,4,5)\in W$, so $(5,5,6,7)\in U+W$. Note that $5$ isn't even since the "first two things" in the element of $U$ and the "first three things" in the element of $W$ can be different.

---

A useful thing to keep in mind is that the variables in set-builder notation are "dummy variables", a.k.a. ["bound variables"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables): the notation means the same thing no matter what variables you have. A way to get at the right answer is to make these variables all different to make it easier to think about.
$U=\left\{(a,a,b,b)\in\mathbf{F}^4:a,b\in\mathbf{F}\right\}$ and $V=\left\{(c,c,c,d)\in\mathbf{F}^4:c,d\in\mathbf{F}\right\}$. Then $U+W=\left\{(a+c,a+c,b+c,b+d)\in\mathbf{F}^4:a,b,c,d\in\mathbf{F}\right\}$. Clearly this is a subset of $\left\{(x,x,y,z)\in\mathbf{F}^4:x,y,z\in\mathbf{F}\right\}$. To show that it's a superset, set $a=x-y,b=0_{\mathbf{F}},c=y,d=z$.